# Android Lint: Is it possible to publish a lint check in a jar file (not aar) on Maven

Tags: java, android, maven, kotlin, android-lint

I've made a lint check, simple java-only (kotlin) module, put it in a jar file and I plan to upload it to Maven Central as a jar. I started with publishing to maven local for test.

I put the required `Lint-Registry-v2` in jar's manifest and I'm confident it's there. Lint check itself is there and working in tests, `IssueRegistry` is there. Then I mention this library in my Android project's `build.gradle`, in `implementation` clause, so it **is** on the classpath, and it **is** seen by Android Studio.

But still lint check doesn't work and isn't being seen by the lint tool: I try to find it with `Run Inspection By Name...` action and it's not there.

I even tried doing `lintChecks 'my.lint.check:version'` but it didn't work too.

Is it simply not possible? Do I have to distribute it through aar on Maven and is this the only option?

Comment: Not sure if you are using Android Studio 4.1 or not. It seems there are some issues with custom lint and Android Studio 4.1 https://groups.google.com/g/lint-dev/c/2gnl0GUcrLk

Comment: @LongRanger I am. Thanks will check again after it'll be updated to 4.2